# Empty text box using requiredvalidator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently involved in developing a system using asp.net(VB). I have applied required validator so that to obtain correct inputs from user. But now I am having some issues. I also must allow the user to leave the text boxes empty too. Then can submit the page. so consider the form can validate true if thetext box are left empty or with values.

how to solve this issue frends? Kindly help me. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

When you use a required Validator, the text will be `required`. Hence the name...
If you want more complex validation you need to use a `CustomValidator`

```
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Text not long enough" ValidationGroup="myGroup" ClientValidationFunction="myCustomValidation"></asp:CustomValidator>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myCustomValidation(oSrc, args) {
            var textboxValue = args.Value;
            if (textboxValue == "") {
                args.IsValid = true;
            } else {
                if (textboxValue.length > 4) {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                } else {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }                
            }
        }
    </script>
```